# vim conceal with more than one character

Tags: vim, unicode, syntax-highlighting

Actually I'd like to display `->` with `→` (there is a space after the arrow) in haskell files. But I have the impression the conceal mechanism only work to replace `->` by one character. An undesirable effect is visually bad indentation.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Edit: Actually I use this, (from `haskell.vim` (conceal enhancement) plugin)

```
syntax match hsNiceOperator "<-" conceal cchar=←
```

Comment: What is your way to replace one character with another?

Comment: I edited my answer, actually I use the conceal mecanism used for syntax highlighting

Comment: can you post the compisition of `"→ "` - it appears to be essential to the question?

Comment: @sehe I just mean to display two characters by two characters and not only one unicode char. I don't really understand what you mean by composition.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? @yogsototh

Answer (score 21):

I do exactly what you want in C. The trick is to conceal each character separately, like so:

```
syn match ArrowHead contained ">" conceal cchar=▶
syn match ArrowTail contained "-" conceal cchar=─
syn match ArrowFull "->" contains=ArrowHead,ArrowTail
```

You might find that ArrowHead or ArrowTail gets matched outside an ArrowFull, unfortunately. This is because existing syntax rules use `contains=ALLBUT,...` or something similar.

To fix this in C, I added ArrowTail and ArrowHead to the cParenGroup cluster, which seems to prevent any problems.

```
syn cluster cParenGroup add=ArrowTail,ArrowHead
```

You may need to do something similar for Haskell.

Since I don't use the conceal feature at all otherwise, I tell Vim to go ahead and "conceal" the arrows ALL the time:

```
set conceallevel=1 concealcursor=nvic
```

BTW if you don't like the default colors for the conceal chars, you can change them like this:

```
hi conceal ctermfg=DarkBlue ctermbg=none guifg=DarkBlue guibg=none
```

Comment: "because existing syntax rules use `contains=ALLBUT,...` or something similar." : use `containedin=ArrowFull` at end of `syn match ArrowHead [...]` and `syn match ArrowTail [...]`, then.

Comment: @user2987828 This doesn't work for me in Vim 7.4. I get false positive ArrowHeads and ArrowTails inside #defines.

Answer (score 5):

Super-old question, but in case anyone else is trying to figure this out, I have had success with the following:

```
call matchadd('Conceal', '<-\&<', 10, -1, {'conceal':'←'})
call matchadd('Conceal', '<\zs-', 10, -1, {'conceal':' '})
hi Conceal        ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=red guifg=red
```

The second argument of `matchadd` is `<pattern>`. Looking at `:help pattern` tells us that a `pattern` is one or more `branches` separated by `\|`, and a `branch` is one or more `concats` separated by `\&`. From the docs: "[a `branch`] matches the last `concat`, but only if all the preceding `concats` also match at the same position."

So in the first call we specify a `pattern` with one branch (there are no `\|` values), made of two `concats`. The first `concat` matches the full arrow, and the second matches the first character of the arrow. Thus, the last `concat` is the `<` which is all that is taken as the match for the conceal parameter, but this only matches if the `<` appears in a `<-`. The second call gives a `pattern` with one `branch` and one `concat`. The pattern begins with the `<` but the match is reset with the `zero-width` atom `\zs` which resets the match at the next character, the `-`, which is concealed with a space. The `hi Conceal` is just highlighting.

In my testing `<` by itself doesn't get turned into `←` and `-` by itself isn't turned into a space.

Hope this helps someone :)